# Using fade prop on AniLink is not rendering animation

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to setup animations on my Gatsby site. I can get all of the default animations to work just fine using AniLink -- except the one that I want to use! Swipe, cover, and paintDrip are 100% functional, but when I insert fade it doesn't work.

Using Gatsby 2.4.17

I've attempted to install gatsby-plugin-layout to see if this would help with animations. I couldn't end up getting the layout plugin to work properly. I reverted to an earlier commit and after several hours I'm at a loss. I cloned a working example repo that uses AniLink fade and it functions properly, so it's something buggy with my project I guess. It is so strange that all other default animations are functional.

Header code:

```js
import AniLink from 'gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink';
```

```js
<div className={headerStyles.wordmark}>
    <AniLink fade to="/">
        <img alt="wordmark" src={data.contentfulWordmark.wordmark.file.url} />
    </AniLink>
</div>
```

Gatsby-config plugins code:

```js
plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-transition-link',
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'src',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`
      }
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
            options: {
              maxWidth: 750,
              linkImagesToOriginal: false
            }
          }
        ]
```

I expected that AniLink would add a fade transition to my link just as swipe, cover, and paintDrip did.

The actual result is:

No error messages in the console and the new page that AniLink points to (to="/") is correctly loaded, but without the animation. It seems that it actually can break links in some random testing. If you click back and forth too fast it renders an empty page. This was what made me initially think I was in need of gatsby-plugin-layout. But once I couldn't get that to work properly... I am lost.

Comment: You ever got this to work? I literally have the same issue you described above.

Comment: I never did. My suspicion is that something in my css was “breaking” it...meaning - I could see a slight fast fade but it was not smooth and seemed glitchy. Upon retrospect I believe it was a conflict with my other animations. I ended up using a mixture of js and css to employ page transitions. Best of luck!

Comment: Ohh, that could be. I'm using Bootstrap for the record.. maybe there was a conflict or something. Thanks for responding!